# Golang - Finding implementations of a particular interface

Tags: go

In Java, the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) show potential implementations of classes and interfaces etc. Is there something similar for Go?

Comment: [guru](https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru), and most editors already make use of this tool.

Comment: sweet! thanks for that =)

Comment: Goland does it for you. Not sure about the sublime/vscode plugins though.